# Point to different data dirs in solrj?

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using solrj for a distributed search. Based on certain user preferences, I will have to search through a particular set of indexes. Is there any way through which I can programatically(duh!) specify the datadir for that particular search query?

I did snoop through the documentation, but couldn't find anyway other than having the datasets in different cores, is there a better way?

Edit 1 : All the set of indexes have the same schema format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `dataDir` almost dynamically using the [CREATE CoreAdmin action](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#CREATE), and specifying a `dataDir` parameter.

> Creates a new core based on preexisting
>   instanceDir/solrconfig.xml/schema.xml, and registers it. If
>   persistence is enabled (persist=true), the configuration for this new
>   core will be saved in 'solr.xml'. If a core with the same name exists,
>   while the "new" created core is initalizing, the "old" one will
>   continue to accept requests. Once it has finished, all new request
>   will go to the "new" core, and the "old" core will be unloaded.

Anyway you'll need to load a new core, it isn't possible changing the data directory without doing it.

You can use solrj to invoke CoreAdmin action using the [`CoreAdminRequest`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/CoreAdminRequest.html) and [`CoreAdminResponse`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/CoreAdminResponse.html) classes.

Comment: Almost same as handling it in a separate core right @javanna?

Comment: @greenhorn yeah, it's similar, but with this solution you'll have only one core running and you will change the `dataDir` on it.

Comment: Yeah! I am just doing a bit of research and ll update here if something turns around.